# What is the Matlab equivalent to Python's `not in`?

Tags: python, matlab

In Python, one could get elements that are exclusive to `lst1` using:

```
lst1=['a','b','c']
lst2=['c','d','e']
lst3=[]
for i in lst1:
    if i not in lst2:
        lst3.append(i)
```

What would be the Matlab equivalent?

Comment: also: `set(lst1) - set(lst2)`

Comment: @gauteh So long as you don't care about number of repetitions of each element. eg `set()` wouldn't work correctly if `lst1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for MATLAB's [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) -

```
setdiff(lst1,lst2)
```

Sample run -

```
>> lst1={'a','b','c'};
>> lst2={'c','d','e'};
>> setdiff(lst1,lst2)
ans = 
    'a'    'b'
```

Verify with Python run -

```
In [161]: lst1=['a','b','c']
     ...: lst2=['c','d','e']
     ...: lst3=[]
     ...: for i in lst1:
     ...:     if i not in lst2:
     ...:         lst3.append(i)
     ...:         

In [162]: lst3
Out[162]: ['a', 'b']
```

In fact, you have `setdiff` in Python's [`NumPy module`](http://www.numpy.org/) as well, as [`numpy.setdiff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html). The equivalent implementation with it would be -

```
In [166]: import numpy as np

In [167]: np.setdiff1d(lst1,lst2) # Output as an array
Out[167]: 
array(['a', 'b'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [168]: np.setdiff1d(lst1,lst2).tolist() # Output as list
Out[168]: ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: MATLAB's `setdiff`  oerates as if the inputs are true algebraic sets, i.e. no element is repeated. (if it is repeated, that's ignored when calculating the differences)  I ended up writing an `R` function "vecdiff" to handle differences in collections of elements where some values are repeated; this may be necessary in MATLAB, depending on the OP's actual needs.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, MATLAB would only keep unique elements in the output. To keep duplicates, one can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) - `lst1(~ismember(lst1,lst2))`. So, `R` natively doesn't have something similar to `setdiff`?

Comment: `R` has a `setdiff` which works just like Matlab's so far as I know.   I wrote "vecdiff" as an alternative which does: `vecdiff(c(1,1,1,2,3),c(1,3,4))` returns  `c(1,1,2)`  .